# How to use boost to run thread another object function with callback

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous

I was trying to run boost::thread some object function with callback

in class A there is a function like this:

```
void DoWork(int (*callback)(float))   
{
float variable = 0.0f;

 boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
int result = f(variable);
}
```

in MAIN:

```
int SomeCallback(float variable)
{
  int result;
  cout<<"Callback called"<<endl;
  //Interpret variable

  return result;
}



int main(){
  A* file = new A();

boost::thread bt(&A::DoWork, file , &SomeCallback );
cout<<"Asyns func called"<<endl;
bt.join();
cout<<"main done"<<endl; 
}
```

The line `boost::thread bt(&A::DoWork, file , &SomeCallback );` causes **linker** errors. This call I took from this tutorial:
http://antonym.org/2009/05/threading-with-boost---part-i-creating-threads.html.

The error is :

```
unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall A::DoWork(int (__cdecl*)(float))" (?DoWork@A@@QAEXP6AHM@Z@Z) referenced in function _main
```

What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Is `callback` ever used in `DoWork`?

Comment: You might be interested in [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/) for your async needs.

Comment: @DrewDormann I guess thats a typo/copy error - `f` and `callback` are most likely the same.

Comment: Yes, problem with copying again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *unresolved external symbol* is a linker error, meaning that the linker cannot find the definition of `A::DoWork`. From your code I cannot see where you actually defined the function, but let me guess:

```
//A.h

class A {
  //...
public:
  void DoWork(int (*callback)(float)); //declaration
};

//A.cpp

void DoWork(int (*callback)(float))   
{
  float variable = 0.0f;

  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
  int result = f(variable);
}
```

I.e. *if* the definition appears exactly as you posted it, in your .cpp file, then the error is that you did not define `A::DoWork` but instead defined a new, free function.

Correct definition then would be:

```
//A.cpp

void A::DoWork(int (*callback)(float))   //define it as a member of A!
{
  float variable = 0.0f;

  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
  int result = f(variable);
}
```

If my guess is wrong, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that we can assess what the real problem is.

Comment: No shame, that happens every so often to many people, normally by just copying the function signature from header to cpp and forgetting to write the `A::` - it's one of the first things one should look for if one gets unresolved references.

Comment: Yes, it was during copying. Many thanks. And what if I would like to call some int SomeCallback method that instead of being defined in Main.cpp is defined as part of for example class A? This time I have for sure correctly defined the method and get the compilation error. I am trying to run this using boost::thread bt(&A::DoWork, file, &A::SomeCallback );

Comment: In that Case I'd use either `boost::function<int(float)>` instead of the function pointer and call it like `boost::thread bt(&A::DoWork, file, boost::bind(&A::SomeCallback, file))`, or if *all* of the callbacks are member functions, use a member function pointer like `void A::DoWork(int (A::*callback)(float)) { this->*callback(0.5f); }`. I'd prefer C++11 with `std::function`and lambdas instead of `bind`.

Comment: Using the binding I got  see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::dm<R,T>' being compiled, and then  "error PRJ0002 : Error result 1 returned from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"

Comment: hm. maybe that should go into a new question? seems like an at best only loosely related problem to me.